# Adding html to div inside update panel in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to add few HTML lines to div that is inside the update panel using the following lines.

```
protected void ListView2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string[] arg = new string[2];
    arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
    listofdisplayblogs.Count();
    DisplayBlog db = listofdisplayblogs.ElementAt(0);
    Blog b = db.DisplayBlogsByYear.ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(arg[1]) - 1);
    div1.InnerHtml = b.BlogContent;
}
```

In design page I have this code inside update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
   <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListView1" EventName="ItemCommand" />
   </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
       <div style="width: 70%; height: 500px; overflow: scroll; scrollbar-3dlight-color: cadetblue; float: right; border: 1px solid black">
       <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a list view above it and updating on Itemcommand.
But i browser I see this error.

```
Cannot read property 'PRM_ParserErrorDetails' of undefined
```

Comment: You probably want to post the relevant JavaScript. I expect the issue is you are looking for an ID that is rendered differently than you expect. Take a look at your rendered HTML and see.

Comment: Yes the rendered HTML id is same in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a placeholder?

```
<ContentTemplate>
    <div style="width: 70%; height: 500px; overflow: scroll; scrollbar-3dlight-color: cadetblue; float: right; border: 1px solid black">
    <div id="div1" runat="server">
         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

And then in you backend code do

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: b.BlogContent is of type String. I am adding html content to div to be display dynamically on list command. It is not adding that html to div in browser though Item command method is called.

Comment: Still waiting for answers?